# The import com.google.cloud.backend.android.mobilebackend cannot be resolved

Tags: android, cloud

I'm implementing the **Mobile Backend Starter**[1] launched today and the sample app has these error "**The import com.google.cloud.backend.android.mobilebackend cannot be resolved**" I import the Google Play Services Library and nothing happen. I'm using Google Apis 4.22 (17)

Thanks!

[1] http://android-developers.blogspot.com.ar/2013/06/bootstrap-your-apps-cloud-services-with.html

Comment: In the libs folder there are some jar. I added all to the build-path and nothing happen

Answer (score 3):

This is very strange.

When I extract the code sample, winrar doesnt extract all because the full path is very long.

Because the code sample havent all the file, the app doesnt compile.

Solution

Open winrar and change the name of the root folder to android

Import the app

Add to the build path all the library found in the libs folder (no google-play-services.jar.properties)

Clean, build and run

Comment: +1 for posting back the solution

Comment: In my case I didn't add "endpoint-libs/libmobilebackend-v1/mobilebackend/mobilebackend-v1-generated-source" as source folder. Adding it as source folder from Java Build Path solves the import error.